# How to solve Pycharm Error :- Unresolved reference: SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

[image: Image link to the error]

I pip installed flask-sqlalchemy on my windows laptop. Pycharm gives out this error and doesn't allow me to import SQLAlchemy. I tried a bunch of solutions:

1. invalidate cache and restart
2. refreshing path

What do i do to fix this ?

Comment: Did you install it in your venv or in your system python ?

Comment: The pip installation was done in my system using windows powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a virtual environment, so you should install it within your venv, not on your main python interpreter. Install it again in the terminal tab in your pycharm project.

Comment: Thanks for your time guys. But I simply deleted the  '.idea' folder of my 'Pycharm Projects' folder and then reset the default interpreter manually to path and allowed the project to build once again from scratch and it worked for me!!